# iOS : AVAudioEngine not starting after sleep

Tags: ios, avaudioengine

We have a problem with the AVEngine that we reproduce only on iPhone 6S plus device. It is fine with other devices we have such as iPhone5s, iPhone6, iPad...
We use AVEngine to do audio capture with tap node on the input node.

We noticed that sleep mode (sleep button) produce a 'AVAudioEngineConfigurationChangeNotification' call when the AVEngine is in paused or stopped state (when AVEngine is running then we can go to sleep and the AVEngine stay in running state).

When we go out from sleep and start the AVEngine (no exception on start), this one is always stopped and we receive the 'AVAudioEngineConfigurationChangeNotification' again...

The next call to start is not stopped (no notification) and everything is working fine again.

Does somebody already observed this strange behavior with the AVEngine?
Is there a way to avoid it?

Regards,

Loïc